# Unable to enumerate USB no configurations huawei Router

Tags: usb-modem, router, huawei

Here's the error message I get when I connect a Huawei B310s-22 Router to my Ubuntu.

To get a USB connection out of the device, [online tutorials](https://routerunlock.com/unlock-huawei-b310s-22-optimus-portugal-router/) indicate soldering a USB connection onto allocated positions on the motherboard of the Router

```
[  310.522463] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 113 using xhci_hcd
[  310.650914] usb 3-1: no configurations
[  310.650919] usb 3-1: can't read configurations, error -22
[  310.762450] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 114 using xhci_hcd
[  310.890912] usb 3-1: no configurations
[  310.890917] usb 3-1: can't read configurations, error -22
[  311.002444] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 115 using xhci_hcd
[  311.018856] usb 3-1: no configurations
[  311.018860] usb 3-1: can't read configurations, error -22
[  311.130437] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 116 using xhci_hcd
[  311.146918] usb 3-1: no configurations
[  311.146921] usb 3-1: can't read configurations, error -22
[  311.146946] usb usb3-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

How can I get it to detect the router?